# Турбо - страницы Yandex . Разделить на части

Tags: xml

Например, sitemap у меня в общем файле содержит ссылки на карты по 500 записей (кол-во ссылок растет от кол-ва), а как, в таком случае, делать ссылки с турбо-страницами нужно будет (синтаксис) ? Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]